# Apply skinparam to individual group in PlantUML sequence diagram

Tags: formatting, plantuml

Hi I want to change the border color of only one of my diagrams groups. My current attempt seems to always set a global for all groups:-

```
@startuml

group Blue group
    TEST1->TEST2: Test1
end
group Red group
    skinparam sequenceGroupBorderColor red
    TEST1->TEST2: Test2
end
@enduml
```

How can I do this?

(also posted on plantuml forum: https://forum.plantuml.net/10716/apply-skinparam-to-individual-group-in-sequence-diagram)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

OK - you can customise individual elements via the it's <<.stereotype>> but only certain objects can have this, and I don't believe groups are one of them.

Luckily there is the following syntax to work around this limitation::

```
group#Blue #LightBlue  Blue
    TEST1->TEST2: Test1
end group
group#Red #violet Red
    TEST1->TEST2: Test2
end group
```

Found in https://forum.plantuml.net/6410/can-we-format-groups-or-have-different-styles-for-group-alt